# Notation of supermatrices

Tags: supersymmetry, notation, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

I am trying to understand supermatrices. First I want to know the notation of supermatrices. In [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03165), it is mentioned $(2|4|2) \times (2|2)$ supermatrices. What are $(2|4|2) \times (2|2)$ supermatrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the notation $(n_b|n_f)$ denotes the dimension of a [super vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space) of Grassmann-even dimension $n_b$ and [Grassmann-odd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) dimension $n_f$. When writing a super vector as a column vector, it is standard to order the Grassmann-even sector before the Grassmann-odd sector.

However, the authors introduce a non-standard ordering $(n_{b_1}|n_f|n_{b_2})$ where parts of the Grassmann-even sector is listed in the bottom of the column vector, see eq. (4.1) on p. 8.

Concretely, a $(2|4|2) \times (2|2)$ super matrix is a matrix representation of a linear map from a super vector space of dimensions $(2|2)$ to a super vector space of dimensions $(2|4|2)$.

References:

1. C. Vergu, *Twistor Parametrization of Locally BPS Super-Wilson Loops,* [arXiv:1605.03165](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03165).